# Telegram Bot c# CallbackQuery

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Здравствуйте!
Уже успел сломать голову с Telegram.Bot.

Я использую webhook, всё прекрасно работает, но как только я решил подключить к приложению inline клавиатуру, тот тут-то и начались проблемы.
Я подключил клавиатуру, она отображается, однако при нажатии на кнопку мне должен отдаваться callback_query, однако происходит ошибка "System.NullReferenceException".

Соответственно в update.CallbackQuery ничего не попадает.

Может быть я сформулировал непонятно, за что прошу прощения, но также прошу помощи, ибо устал копать api телеграма.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostAsync(Update update)
        {
    switch (update.Type)
                    {
                        case UpdateType.MessageUpdate:    
                             if (message.Text.StartsWith("/inline"))
                             {
                                 await Botz.api.SendChatActionAsync(message.Chat.Id, Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums.ChatAction.Typing);

                                 var keyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(new[]
                                     {
                                    new[]
                                    {
                                        new InlineKeyboardButton{ Text="1.1", Url="https://vk.com/"},
                                        new InlineKeyboardButton{Text="1.2",SwitchInlineQuery = "1.2"},
                                    },
                                    new[]
                                    {
                                        new InlineKeyboardButton{Text="2.1",CallbackData="he"},
                                        //new InlineKeyboardButton{Text="2.2",CallbackData="2.2"},
                                    }
                                });

                                await Task.Delay(500);

                                await Botz.api.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, "Choose", replyMarkup: keyboard);
                            }
                            break;
                    case UpdateType.CallbackQueryUpdate:
                        Console.WriteLine("CallBack enable");
                        await Botz.api.EditInlineMessageTextAsync(update.CallbackQuery.InlineMessageId, "test");
                        await Botz.api.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(update.CallbackQuery.Id, text: "test");
                        break;
                  }
       }
```

Comment: Весьма помог бы в понимании проблемы кусок проблемного кода

Comment: Я добавил код, извиняюсь, что сразу не сообразил добавить его.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что Вы путаете понятия `InlineButton` и `InlineMessage`.
Ваши методы

```
await Botz.api.EditInlineMessageTextAsync(update.CallbackQuery.InlineMessageId, "test");
await Botz.api.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(update.CallbackQuery.Id, text: "test");
```

предназначены как раз-таки для работы с `InlineMessage` в Inline-режиме. Замените их на этот метод

```
Botz.api.EditMessageTextAsync(update.CallbackQuery.Message.Chat.Id, update.CallbackQuery.Message.MessageId, "test");
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. К сожалению это немного не та проблема, с которой я борюсь. Проблема в том, что у меня не срабатывает даже "Console.WriteLine("CallBack enable");", который находится в "case UpdateType.CallbackQueryUpdate:"

Comment: @Camypai на какой строке ошибка?

Comment: Боюсь, что ни в какой. Единственное сообщение, которое я получаю: "Вызвано исключение: "System.NullReferenceException" в Webhook_0.2.exe". Происходит это исключение при нажатии на инлайн кнопку.

Comment: @Camypai так Вы даже дебажить не пробовали?

Comment: Обычно такие эксепшены бывают, например, при обращении к полю типа, в случае если тип пришёл другой. То есть пришло в апдейте фото, а пытаетесь получить из него аудио (очень обобщённый пример).

Comment: Прогоните дебагом